# Maven genera error en la carpeta target

Tags: java, spring, maven

Tengo una aplicación en STS, cuando pongo mvn clean install retorna Build success pero genera con errores la carpeta de target y target/generated-sources, alguien tiene idea de por qué puede pasar esto? [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando dices "genera con errores", es porqué verdaderamente hay errores en su contenido o simplemente porqué Eclipse te pone el icono rojo de error?

Comment: Si pasas el raton sobre el icono de error, que te dice exactamente?